# jQuery - Display URL of iFrame clicked

Tags: iframe

I have MySQL database with multiple URL's.
Each URL is displayed in one iframe, so 3 URL's = 3 iframes. I display them like this.

```
...
$resu = mysql_fetch_array ($consultation);
echo "<iframe src='".$resu['URL']."' onload='load(this)' id='iframe'></iframe>";
...
```

With this script I'm able to know the URL of the iframe clicked (not exactly, besides it doesn't work in jsFiddle but in my PC yes. (http://jsfiddle.net/7UxHv/)).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('iframe#iframe').load(function(){
        alert($('#iframe').attr('src'));
    });
});
</script>
```

But really it displays the first database row and not the one clicked.

Anyway to display the one clicked with that script or another form to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

Note you are generating multiple elements with the same id..  id should be unique.

This might be why you get only the first row to work.

---

I think the below code should work:

Html:

```
<iframe src='.$resu['URL'].' onload='loadIframe(this)' scrolling='no'></iframe>​
```

JS:

```
window.loadIframe = function(frame) {
    alert("Loaded "+$(frame).attr('src'));
}
```

Comment: iframe can't have an exact url, it was an example. i need it like in the OP. iframe src='".$resu['URL'].", because i display results from database with PHP

Comment: probably it's what you say, all the iframes have the same id, but iframe must have an id to associate it with jquery, then how do i do?

Comment: you don't need the id - when the event handler is called (be it a click event or load event) the "this" variable is pointing to the element that triggered the event, so you can do $(this) instead of $('#id-of-element')

Comment: aaaaa ok ok but i use id for one reason, because i have another script, now i need to combine it with this script, if you do this you are god :) http://pastebin.com/Zjrtz8CG

Comment: Give a class to the iframes you want the 2nd script to run on, (eg. class="reload-counter") and then setup the other script by $('.reload-counter').load(...)  instead of by using id.   In general if you want to trigger code for multiple elements use a class and not id.

Comment: your help has been incredible, without you, this would have been impossible for me! thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this... change 'src' to 'data-src'... and try the following...

```
echo "<iframe data-src='".$resu['URL']."' onload='load(this)' id='iframe'></iframe>";

$('#iframe').click(function() {
    alert($('#iframe').data('src'));
});
```

also instead of using onload try using onclick()...

Might work...

Comment: i've tried hundreds of things, and i think that onclick doesn't work. now i'll try data-src, which i don't know what's the difference with src x)

Comment: iframe doesn't display with attribute data-src, it only displays with src.